# Lock on installing

Tags: installation, call-screening

My brother is installing apps every time. I make an app lock password but he download the apk and install games. How I stop installation of apps

Answer (score 0):

MacroDroid [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) can save u: Let's be simple;

1. Download and install MacroDroid
2. Press Add Macro
3. Select Trigger to be Application Launched
4. Check non-launchable apps
5. Locate Package installer and select it
6. Go to Actions tab
7. Select Launch Home Screen
8. Go to constraints and chose any other thing you want it to consider before executing that action you configured above or just leave it blank
9. Give your Macro a name and save it
10. You're ready to go

Note: *give macrodroid all permissions possible as requested. The macro will look as below*
[image]

Comment: This app is not working. It not stop installation of apps. Tell me other way

Comment: Did you try all the two options

Comment: I am unable to understand the steps. Tell me how to activate this.